# pycharm IDE fatal error and new cross-platform PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, pycharm, windows-10

When I opened pycharm app I found this ID error details

[image]

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create extension (class=com.webschik.doT.editor.actions.DotTypedHandler) [Plugin: com.webschik.doT]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createError(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapters(ExtensionPointImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.calcExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.java:241)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointName.java:39)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.TypedHandler$TypedHandlerDelegatePreloader.preload(TypedHandler.java:687)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$executePreloadActivity$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:412)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:705)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:647)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:63)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.executePreloadActivity(ApplicationLoader.kt:402)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader.access$executePreloadActivity(ApplicationLoader.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$executePreloadActivities$2.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:467)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create class com.webschik.doT.editor.actions.DotTypedHandler (classloader=PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=doT, id=com.webschik.doT, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=~\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.2\plugins\idea-doT.jar, version=1.5.4, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=21, state=active))
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:870)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.instantiateClass(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter$SimpleConstructorInjectionAdapter.instantiateClass(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.java:66)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.webschik.doT.DotLanguage
    at com.webschik.doT.parsing.DotElementType.<init>(DotElementType.java:17)
    at com.webschik.doT.parsing.DotTokenTypes.<clinit>(DotTokenTypes.java:12)
    at com.webschik.doT.parsing.DotTokenTypesBySymbol.<clinit>(DotTokenTypesBySymbol.java:12)
    at com.webschik.doT.editor.actions.DotTypedHandler.<init>(DotTypedHandler.java:26)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:830)
    ... 22 more
```

Furthermore, In the terminal, I get these lines :

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\A\D-main\
```

> 

I do not if this a relation between the two issues.

I tried to move to the local environment I created before with command

```
conda activate env
```

but I could not, In spite of the availability of the env environment.

I tried many solution, but the problem of powershell was solved for my windows command line terminal, but It is still available in pycharm.

I tried this line ,it doesn't work with me

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -NoLogo
```

If anyone got this issue before, what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it help if you disable 3rd-party plugins via _File | Settings | Plugins | Gear Icon | Disable All Downloaded Plugins_? It seems that you're using doT plugin that throws the following stacktrace.

Comment: no it does not work with me.